# is it possible to make a method run continuously until I input a special character

Tags: java, methods

I have the code below, my question is : is it possible to make a method run continuously until I input a special character

```
public static int remainder (int dividend, int divisor){
    while ( dividend >= divisor ){
        dividend -= divisor;
    }
    System.out.println("Result: "+ dividend);

    System.out.println("Continue? Y/N"); // if Y, go back and run with different input value, otherwise return the result

    return dividend;
}
```

I'm quite new to java and this only my first question here, hope is not too silly

Comment: You need two threads here.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Two *threads*?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you need to think about your structure differently. The `remainder` method probably shouldn't interact with the console - you need to loop in the code *calling* it:

```
// Calling code, e.g. main
Console console = System.console();
if (console == null) {
    System.out.println("Unable to get console. Aborting.");
    System.exit(1); // Or continue somehow without this...
}

String response;
do {
    console.printf("Enter a dividend: ");
    int dividend = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());

    console.printf("Enter a divisor: ");
    int divisor = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());

    int result = remainder(dividend, divisor);
    console.printf("Result: %d%n", result);
    console.printf("Continue? (Y/N) ");
    response = console.readLine();
} while (response.equals("Y"));
```

Then your `remainder` method should *just* compute the remainder and return it.